# Using the Internet Explorer object to scrape information?

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I am attempting to scrape some information from a website. The link I am referencing is: https://web.tmxmoney.com/quote.php?qm_symbol=WEED

I'm creating an Internet Explorer object with the following:

```
Dim appIE As Object
Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

Dim ticker As String
ticker = "BRB"

With appIE
    .Navigate "https://web.tmxmoney.com/quote.php?qm_symbol=" & ticker
    .Visible = False
End With

Do While appIE.Busy
Loop
```

I am then attempting to get the contents of a class with the following:

```
Set testing = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("quote-name")(0).textContent
Debug.Print (testing)
```

However, I am receiving the error: `Type Mismatach`. The following code will run fine though: `appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("quote-name")`.

My desired content is the following and can run this fine in the IE console.

```
"
                    Brick Brewing Co. Limited
                    Exchange: TSX Exchange |
                                                        Jul 26, 2017, 2:46 PM EDT                                               "
```

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Comment: that web page appears to have script errors ... internet explorer throws an error ... change your code to `.Visible = True`

Answer (score 1):

Try these lines of code

testing = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("quote-name")(0).textContent

Debug.Print (testing)

Comment: You have used set to get the text property. Don't use set.  I have not used "set" for getting the value